# If statement with Checkbox in jQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a problem with this one:

```
if($("#Autotag").is(":checked"))
{
alert("Just to check if it works");
}
```

But it won't give me the alert dialog while it's checked!
I've been looking for right answers.  All the other codes I've written does work but not this one.

jsFiddle ain't giving me any hints as person told me to try...
I've also been reading this How to: [jQuery how to](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.fi/2008/12/how-to-check-if-checkbox-is-checked.html)

Comment: how do you run this code?

Comment: `document.getElementById('Autotag').checked` is [FAR more efficient](http://vanilla-js.com/)

Comment: Is it checked by default or are you trying to check it after the page loads without encasing it in change evnt

Comment: @Kolink OP wasn't asking for an optimization solution.

Comment: @Blazemonger That's why it's a comment, not an answer ;)

Comment: @Blazemonger I can't vote up. Need to get 15 votes before I can vote. All I can do what I see on this screen is commenting that is allowed for me. :)

Comment: You can still accept answers to your own questions. Look for the empty checkmark below the voting arrows.

Comment: Thanks @Blazemonger :) Sometimes I'm just blind to see those kind of things :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That code will not run when the person checks the checkbox, it will just tell you the state of the checkbox at that moment in time it has run.

If you want to know when it is checked, you need to listen for the change event. The following code assumes you call this onready or after the element is added to the page.

```
$("#Autotag").on("change", function () {
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        alert("Just to check if it works");
    }
});
```

Comment: You made it before me, here is the [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/QJ5NW/) to support your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be calling this inside a change event, instead of just calling it once

```
$("#Autotag").change(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  if ( $this.is(":checked") ) {
    alert("This should work for you");
  }
});
```

Comment: While I appreciate the fact that you cached the result of `$(this)`, it's still moot when compared to `this.checked` ;)

Comment: Not a problem, and its force of habit to cache things anymore